# Angular Reactive Forms Input Error (input field not showing)

Tags: angular, forms, form-control, formgroups

I've created a dynamic form (Angular 10) that dynamically gets `FormControlNames` via a call to the backend `(Django/DjangoRestFramework)`.

The `FormControlNames` are the names of the articles I want the users to see. Users will have to write in each input field binded to the correct `FormControlName` the quantity of each article showed and then submit the whole thing.

The problem: altough I can see the FormControlNames get correctly created (showed by):

```
  {{myForm?.value|json}}
```

Users can't put any value for the newly created FormControlNames because the input fields don't appear.
What can I do to get the input fields box to show? I don't get any error on the console. Input boxes just don't appear.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZfUFH.png)

Backend File/Response:

```
[
    {
        "id": 16,
        "nomeart": "Gambero Abbattuto",
        "completed": false,
        "desart": "code abbattute alla fonte",
        "codiceart": "zgamberiiiiii",
        "peso": 1,
        "taglia": 0,
        "um": "kg"
    },
    {
        "id": 15,
        "nomeart": "Branzino Fresco",
        "completed": false,
        "desart": "è un branzino",
        "codiceart": "ilbraaaa",
        "peso": 1,
        "taglia": 0,
        "um": "kg"
    },
    {...}

]
```

File: component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ServerService } from 'src/app/server.service';
import { DataService } from "./data.service";
import { AuthService } from 'src/app/auth.service';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup,
  Validators, FormArray,
  ReactiveFormsModule, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { delay } from 'rxjs/operators';

  interface articoli {
    id: 'number',
    nomeart: 'string',
    completed: 'boolean',
    desart: 'string',
    codiceart: 'string',
    peso: 'number',
    taglia: 'number',
    um: 'string',
  }

  interface Pezzi {
    value: string;
  }


@Component({
  selector: 'app-ordine',
  templateUrl: './ordine.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./ordine.component.scss']
})
export class OrdineComponent implements OnInit {

  myForm: FormGroup;

  articoli: any;

  articolo= {
    id: 'number',
    nomeart: 'string',
    completed: 'boolean',
    desart: 'string',
    codiceart: 'string',
    peso: 'number',
    taglia: 'number',
    um: 'string',
  }

  constructor(
    private server: ServerService,
    private authService: AuthService,
    public dialog: MatDialog,
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private dataService: DataService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {

    this.server.request('GET', '/api/v1/articolo-list/')
    .subscribe((data: any) => {
      if (data) {
        this.articoli = data;
      }
    });

    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      title: ["", []],
      articoli: this.fb.group({})
    });
    this.getThings();

  }

  getThings() { 
    this.dataService.getThings().subscribe(data => {
      this.articoli = data;
      this.dataService.arty.forEach(x => {
        (this.myForm.get("articoli") as FormGroup).addControl(
          x.nomeart,
          this.fb.control("0")
        );
      });
    });

  }



  nrpezzi: Pezzi[] = [
    { value: '0'},
    { value: '1'},
    { value: '2'},
    { value: '3'},
    { value: '4'},
    { value: '5'},    
    { value: '6'},
    { value: '7'},
    { value: '8'},
    { value: '9'},
    { value: '10'},
    { value: '11'},
    { value: '12'},
    { value: '13'},
    { value: '14'},
    { value: '15'},
    { value: '16'},
    { value: '17'},
    { value: '18'},
    { value: '19'},
    { value: '20'},
    { value: '21'},
    { value: '22'},
    { value: '23'},
    { value: '24'},
    { value: '25'},
    { value: '26'},
    { value: '27'},
    { value: '28'},
    { value: '29'},
    { value: '30'},
    { value: '31'},
    { value: '32'},
    { value: '33'},
    { value: '34'},
    { value: '35'},
    { value: '36'},
    { value: '37'},
    { value: '38'},
    { value: '39'},
    { value: '40'},
    { value: '41'},
    { value: '42'},
    
  ];

}
```

File: dataservice.ts

```
import { Injectable, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { of } from "rxjs";
import { delay } from "rxjs/operators";
import { ServerService } from 'src/app/server.service';
import { AuthService } from 'src/app/auth.service';
import { OrdineComponent } from './ordine.component';

interface articoli {
  id: 'number',
  nomeart: 'string',
  completed: 'boolean',
  desart: 'string',
  codiceart: 'string',
  peso: 'number',
  taglia: 'number',
  um: 'string',
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})

export class DataService {

  constructor(
    private server: ServerService,
    private authService: AuthService,
  ) {}

  
  arty:articoli[] =[];


  articolo= {
    id: 'number',
    nomeart: 'string',
    completed: 'boolean',
    desart: 'string',
    codiceart: 'string',
    peso: 'number',
    taglia: 'number',
    um: 'string',
  }

  
  getThings() {

    this.server.request('GET', '/api/v1/articolo-list/')
    .subscribe((data: any) => {
      if (data) {
        this.arty = data;
        console.log(data);
      }
    });

    return of(
   [this.articolo.nomeart]
  ).pipe(delay(200));
  }
}
```

File: component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
    ...
    <div formGroupName="articoli">
        <mat-card *ngFor="let articolo of arty">
            <input [formControlName]=
            "articolo.nomeart"> 
        </mat-card>
    </div>
  </form>
  {{myForm?.value|json}}
  <hr/>
```

Does anyone know what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<mat-card *ngFor="let articolo of arty">
in the above line just checking have you assigned the value of arty in respective component ts layer which displays the html, please check whether arty list value is comming are or not as you checked like for the myform

Comment: Sorry but I did not understand what you were trying to explain.

For simplicity, instead of "mat-card", consider I put "div": "<div *ngFor="let articolo of arty"> " ;

Please, can you try to explain again to me your advice "have you assigned the value of arty in respective component ts layer which displays the html" ? How should I check if whether arty list value is comming are or not as you checked like for the myform?

Comment: here  you are placing the input element inside the ng for loop , so if the value of arty is empty , the input element will not render, so can you please check the value of arty list  example like  {{arty|json}} in the html layer

Comment: yes, you were right, the value of arty is null! i thought i was filling it with the api call, but i was wrong. So, now, do you have any advice on how I can get trough that problem? thank you for your time!

Comment: i'm doing infinite tests and if I use "let articolo of arty", FormControlnames get created as you already saw on my question. If I instead try to use "let articolo of articoli", the input boxes comes out but are unusable because, this time " Cannot find control with path: articoli -> Gambero Abbattuto" (gambero abbattuto is a value of the various articolo.nomeart).
So, if I can get FormControlNames, i can't get the input boxes and viceversa. 
Any idea?

Comment: @utenteserio thanks for the info, so when the values is present you can able to see the input element am i correct ? And  sorry am not able to understand what issue you are facing whether getting the data from api call or getting the formControlName. assuming if you are asking how you to getting the data suggesting this - you should the assign arty property value in component layer by getting the data from data service layer, you need to fetch the arty data from data service and should assign the value.

Comment: Cannot find control with path for this please make sure whatever form control name you are building for the form in ts component layer should match the value of the form control name you are dynamically assigning in html layer.

Comment: Thank you for your help Rrocky555